# How to add nested object to fetch POST body?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Given a simple fetch request i.e.

```
   fetch('https://api.com/endpoint', {
      method: "POST"
    });
```

Is it possible / how can following object be converted to query params / query string to append to the fetch request? Most methods online recommend using [new URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) helper, however it doesn't seem to work with nested objects and when converted to string these nested objects are returned as `[Object object]` string. Ideal solution should not rely on any third party packages.

```
  {
    side: 'buy',
    symbol: 'AAPL',
    type: 'market',
    qty: '2',
    time_in_force: 'gtc',
    order_class: 'bracket',
    take_profit: {
      limit_price: '200'
    },
    stop_loss: {
      stop_price: '200'
    }
  }
```

Comment: If it were me, I'd consider sending that as the *body* of the fetch request instead of as a query string if at all possible. Bodies are easy to stringify.

Comment: @CertainPerformance could you provide an example please? I just googled this, and I think body still needs to be stringified or something of that sort?

Comment: See the answer below - problem is, the *endpoint* has to be configured for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form your fetch request like this:

```
 fetch('https://api.com/endpoint', {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
     body: JSON.stringify(dataYouWannaPost)

    });
```